# Get fraction between x.66 and x.99

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a query - (CASE - WHEN statement):

```
 --all cols are numbers
case when round((O.POCET - O.P_DEL - O.P_DEL_DOD - O.P_FAK - O.P_VYD - O.P_OBJ)/SK.VELKE_BAL,3) 
 between 0.66 and 0.99 then 1 
when round((O.POCET - O.P_DEL - O.P_DEL_DOD - O.P_FAK - O.P_VYD - O.P_OBJ)/SK.DOD_BAL,3) 
 between 0.66 and 0.99 then 2 
else 0 end
```

It's working fine, but i need to get numbers between 1.66-1.99, 2.66-2.99 and so on...
IF i use `LIKE`, i can get the fraction, but not between theese numbers.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for a **minimal** example of your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data into that table; your expected output for that sample data; an English (not code) explanation of how you get from the sample data to the output that describes the problem you are trying to solve; details of what your code outputs, where it is wrong and what issue you want solving. At the moment, we have to try to make up all those details and guess what your exact issue is so help us to help you by providing a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want it when the decimal part of the (positive) number is between a range then use the `MOD` function:

```sql
CASE
WHEN MOD(your_sum1, 1) BETWEEN 0.66 AND 0.99
THEN 1
WHEN MOD(your_sum2, 1) BETWEEN 0.66 AND 0.99
THEN 2
ELSE 0
END
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a6e79acbea77fcd44a85aec17361e26a)*